# A question on the truth of a conjectured biconditional

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, divisor-sum

(Note: This has been cross-posted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196452).)

Suppose I have the following series of implications (the underlying assumption is $I(q^k)I(n^2) = 2$), where $I(x) = \sigma(x)/x$ is the *abundancy index* of the positive integer $x$, and $\sigma$ is the *classical sum-of-divisors function*:

> $$\frac{2n}{n + 1} < I(n^2) \Longrightarrow n < q \Longrightarrow k = 1 \Longrightarrow \frac{2n}{n + 1}\left(\frac{q + 1}{q}\right) = \frac{2n}{n + 1} \cdot I(q) < I(q)I(n^2)$$
>
> $$\Longrightarrow \frac{2n}{n + 1}\left(\frac{q + 1}{q}\right) = \frac{2n}{n + 1} \cdot I(q) < I(q)I(n^2) = I(q^k)I(n^2) = 2$$
>
> $$\Longrightarrow \frac{2n\left(q + 1\right)}{\left(n + 1\right)q} < 2 \Longrightarrow 2qn + 2n < 2qn + 2q \Longrightarrow n < q.$$

My question is:  Does this series of implications mean that the biconditional

> $$n < q \Longleftrightarrow k = 1$$

is true?

Thanks!

[Edit (February 13, 2015): As mentioned in the comments, the truth of the reverse implication $k = 1 \Longrightarrow n < q$ would depend on whether the inequality

$$\frac{2n}{n + 1} < I(n^2)$$

is indeed true.  Per the answer to this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141679), the limiting proportion of $n$ satisfying this last inequality is $0$. Since this inequality is equivalent to $n < q$, heuristically this means that we can *reasonably expect* $q < n$ to be true, although this is far from a rigorous proof.]

[**Update as of March 05, 2020** [(Brown, 2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591), [(Dris, 2017)](http://nntdm.net/volume-23-2017/number-4/01-13/), and [(Starni, 2018)](http://nntdm.net/volume-24-2018/number-1/5-9/) have all claimed/published (independent) proofs for the inequality $q<n$, where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special/Euler prime $q$.]

Comment: Yes; if you have $n < q \Rightarrow k=1 \Rightarrow n < q$, this implies : $n < q \Leftrightarrow k=1$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - I just realized that, in fact, this gives:

$$\frac{2n}{n+1} < I(n^2) \Longleftrightarrow n < q \Longleftrightarrow k = 1.$$

Is this series of biconditionals *equivalent* to:

$$I(n^2) < \frac{2n}{n+1} \Longleftrightarrow q < n \Longleftrightarrow k > 1?$$

If so, is

$$q < n \Longleftrightarrow k > 1$$

*equivalent* to

$$n < q \Longleftrightarrow k = 1?$$

Comment: **NO** : $q < n \Leftrightarrow k > 1$ is equivalent to (negating both LHS and RHS) : $q \ge n \Leftrightarrow k \le 1$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, thanks for the confirmation!  I do know that $q \neq n$ and $k \geq 1$ in my scenario.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, so does this now mean that the biconditional

$$n < q \Longleftrightarrow k = 1$$

holds unconditionally (i.e., it does not depend on the truth of the inequality $\frac{2n}{n + 1} < I(n^2)$)?

Comment: As you wrote on mathoverflow: we know that n < q implies k = 1. We want to prove that k = 1 implies n < q. So I ignore everything left of the first k = 1 and start reading at the first statement of k = 1. The first implication I then encounter is clear. However I don't see the validity of the inequality at the end of that line. It is equivalent to the inequality at the far left (which we don't automatically have if we start with k = 1) of which you wrote at MO that you don't know whether it is true. If you don't know that, you cannot freely use it in a proof that k =1 implies n < q.

Comment: In other words: your proof does not seem to say 'n < q implies k = 1 which by itself implies n < q' but 'n < q implies k = 1, which together with the first inequality implies n < q'. That is something quite different.

Comment: Okay, I get it now.  My profuse thanks, @Vincent!  =)